# Apply function only to certain level of factor?

Tags: r

I have a data frame like so:

```
df <- structure(list(year = c(1990, 1990, 1990, 1990, 1990, 1990, 1990, 
1990, 1990, 1990, 1990, 1990, 1990, 1990, 1990, 1991, 1991, 1991, 
1991, 1991, 1991, 1991, 1991, 1991, 1991, 1991, 1991, 1991, 1991, 
1991), group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A", "B"), class = "factor"), 
    value = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
    13L, 14L, 15L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
    15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L)), .Names = c("year", "group", "value"
), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = "data.frame")


   > df
   year group value
1  1990     A     1
2  1990     A     2
3  1990     A     3
4  1990     A     4
5  1990     A     5
6  1990     A     6
7  1990     B     7
8  1990     B     8
9  1990     B     9
10 1990     B    10
11 1990     B    11
12 1990     B    12
13 1990     B    13
14 1990     B    14
15 1990     B    15
16 1991     A     5
17 1991     A     6
18 1991     A     7
19 1991     A     8
20 1991     A     9
21 1991     A    10
22 1991     A    11
23 1991     A    12
24 1991     A    13
25 1991     A    14
26 1991     B    15
27 1991     B    16
28 1991     B    17
29 1991     B    18
30 1991     B    19
```

I need to apply a function for each year (I intend to do that with `plyr` and `summarise`) but **only** on the factor level with the most rows (A or B). Is there a way to automatically select this level (A or B) for each year?

```
df2 <- ddply(df, .(year), summarise, result="some operation on longest level"))
```

desired output:

```
> df2
   year group value result
1  1990     B     7     5
2  1990     B     8     4
3  1990     B     9     5
4  1990     B    10     3
5  1990     B    11     3
6  1990     B    12     8
7  1990     B    13    11
8  1990     B    14     7  
9  1990     B    15     2
10 1991     A     5    10
11 1991     A     6    13
12 1991     A     7     9
13 1991     A     8     7
14 1991     A     9     6
15 1991     A    10     1
16 1991     A    11    15 
17 1991     A    12     5
18 1991     A    13     5
19 1991     A    14     2
```

Comment: You can use `table` to get you started. E.g. `lapply(split(df, df$year), function(x) table(x$group))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this might be another approach with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

df <- df %.% group_by(year,group) %.% mutate(count = n()) %.% ungroup()
df <- df %.% group_by(year) %.% filter(count %in% max(count)) %.% mutate(result = sqrt(value))
df$count <- NULL
```

since i am not sure what function you want to apply to `result` I used `sqrt(value)` as in @rbatt's answer

Comment: Awesome, thanks very much! I was able to modify this to fit my real data, I was a bit reluctant to use dplyr before but now I am convinced :D

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I don't use plyr myself, but here's how i might do it with base functions. Perhaps that will inspire a plyr solution for you.

```
#find largest groups for each year
maxgroups <- tapply(df$group, df$year, function(x) which.max(table(x)))
#create group names
maxpairs <- paste(names(maxgroups),levels(df$group)[maxgroups], sep=".")

#helper function
ifnotin<-function(val,set,ifnotin) {out<-val; out[!val%in%set]<-ifnotin; droplevels(out)}
#new factor indicating best group
tgroups <- ifnotin(interaction(df$year, df$group), maxpairs, NA)

#now transform the best groups by adding year to result (or whatever transformation you need to do)
transform(df, value=ifelse(!is.na(tgroups), value+year, value))
```

I wasn't sure if your transformation need to know what group/year it was for or not. If you just needed to know if it was in a group that needed transformation you could skip the `tgroups` and just use

```
needstransform <- interaction(df$year, df$group) %in% maxpairs
```

but `tgroups` has NA values that would be good for summaries `tapply(df$value, droplevels(tgroups), mean)` and such

Comment: Nice idea to use `interaction`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a very good answer because it's super obfuscated (and it doesn't use your desired **plyr** approach), but maybe it will stimulate someone else's thinking:

Basically, you just need to know which values of `group` you want to look at for each year. Let's say you figure that out and store those values (in the same order as splits of the original data by `year`) in a variable called `m`, then you can `mapply` some function that subsets each split (of the data by year) by `group` and then does whatever other calculations you want.

```
do.call(rbind, mapply(function(x,y) { 
                          tmp <- x[x$group==y,]
                          #fun(tmp) # apply your function to the relevant subset
                      }, split(df,df$year), m, SIMPLIFY=FALSE))
```

I thought of three different ways you could generate `m`. Here they are:

```
m <- with(df, levels(group)[apply(table(group, year), 2, which.max)])

m <- levels(df$group)[sapply(split(df, df$year), function(x) which.max(sapply(split(x, x$group), nrow)))]

m <- with(df, levels(group)[apply(tapply(year, list(group, year), length),2,which.max)])
```

Comment: just a minor tidbit, i believe ddply is from plyr, while dplyr is an "improved" plyr package

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with:

```
df2 <- ddply(
        df, 
        .(year), 
        summarise, 
        result=sqrt(
            value[group==names(which.max(table(df$group)))]
        )
    )
```

Comment: You seem to be doing some aggregation here, which I don't think is what the OP requested.

Comment: I changed the function being applied – now I take the square root. But I may have misinterpreted something ...